# xcode: difference between adding a linker flag and "link binary with libraries"

Tags: c++, c, xcode, build, linker

I switched a few days ago from windows and I find a bit confusing the linking process in xcode. 
I have a static library I want to use called nag C library whose file is "libnagc_nag.a".
If I add "/opt/NAG/clmi623dgl/lib/libnagc_nag.a" to "other linker flags", the program runs perfectly. 
On the other hand, If i go to "Build Phases -> link binary with libraries -> + -> add other" and add  "libnagc_nag.a", the library file now appears in the project navigator but I get the following error after the build succeeds and it tries to run it.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: 
/fserver/mo/cl23/CL23.3/CLMI623DG_build/BUILD_mac_64/climp/LIBS/nag_lm/libnagc_nag.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/german/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-bjepqyzlzkayspddtaspmmzxgaid/Build/Products/Debug/myproj
Reason: image not found
```

my questions are:

Why is it any different? 
does it think it's a dynamic library?
How can I solve this problem in the second case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: I removed a link to the article where I found the answer since it was outdated.

The problem is that the linker flag is the same for both, dynamic and static libraries, and the file extension is removed from it. So, if you have a static and a dynamic library with the same name and only different extensions, the linker will chose by default the dynamic version of the library. This happens even if you chose the the static version in the "link binary with libraries" menu. Then, if the app can't find the dynamic library there will be an error. So, the answers to the question are:

1) it wouldn't make any difference if there wasn't a dynamic library with the same name. 2) The linker only know the name of the library, so by default it choses the dynamic version. 3) The solution can be renaming the library or using the first method.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Does your project have multiple build targets? If so, did you add the library to the appropriate target? Check this by looking at "link binary with libraries" again or by selected the framework in the Project Navigator and looking at "Target Membership" in the File Inspector pane.

Also, is your framework search path set correctly? Click on your project at the top of your project navigator, then click on "Build Settings" in the top center of the screen, then go down to "Search Paths" and make sure an appropriate path is included.

Comment: no, it has only one target. It's just the default c++ project where I changed the text in main for the text in an example provided by NAG.
The library is added correctly, or at least it is what I see in "target membership". Also, the framework search path and lib path are both the path to the "libnagc_nag.a" file.